# Getting message "The post could not be shared", sharing via sharer.php on multiple smart phones

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

The Sharing URL on smart phone (Fetched from chrome 33.* emulating Samsung Galaxy S3):

```
https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?
m=self
&u=<URL>
&id=<9 digit number>
&sid=0
&error=1
&_rdr
```

The URL is 596 characters long.
The same URL can be shared from desktops.
The URL directs to a page that follows open graph protocol rules, I confirmed that using the Facebook debugger.
The debugger raises no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why facebook sharer with parameter isn't working on mobile site (m.facebook.com/sharer) but as a work around you can add
    ?m2w
to your url to enforce desktop version

Comment: Creative fix. Thank you!